# How to disable right click in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

i want to disable right  click in nautilus using Ubuntu 12.04. how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable right click for just desktop :

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 99"
```

To apply for system wide:

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 2 0 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```

If you want to reverse it:

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = default'
```

**But, notice that it will restore to defaults upon rebooting.**

Now, if you wish to make this option non-volatile do the following:

> open dash --> startup Applications --> Add --> fill as in the image
>   below

[image]

Comment: Its not working. When i apply the xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 99" , its blocking system wide right click but i just want the desktop right click to block.