# How to disable right click in menus?

Tags: 13.10, kubuntu, mouse

i'm having troubles with the right click, because when i press in dolphin or in chrome to open some menu action, the right click open the menu and start the first action in that menu in the same click! i want to disable the right click not for open menus, just for click! or move the menu away of the click position...

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/195503/how-to-disable-right-click-in-nautilus

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. It's Qt toolkit behavior. If it was possible, you are also using other graphical toolkits in applications like Chrome (GTK), so you would have to patch each of them.

I think this is a standard behavior in many toolkits which is too difficult to disable in all applications.